# Android Basics - Two classes show image

Tags: android

I have one main class called `MainActivity.java` and another class `Image.java`

nothing fancy

**MainAcivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Image myimage;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myimage = new Image();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Image.java**

```
     public class Image extends Activity {
ImageView image_view;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),       R.drawable.iguana);
      image_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
       image_view.setImageBitmap(image);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

However, it's never displayed.
If I put the show image code to my MainActivity it does work.
I assume I may not call the Image class correctly.

In my **layout.xml**

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />
```

**€ SOLVED**

Adding following code into my MainActivity.class startet the Image.class
Thank you

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Image.class);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You've forgotten startActivity. However, why not just have the Image.java decode the resource and return the image to the main class and let that display it?

Comment: Make your solution into an Answer instead of including it in the question text.

Answer (score 3):

`Image` is an `Activity`, and you have to start it with `startActivity`. There is no need to instantiate it, android is going to take care of it for you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't display because `Image#onCreate` is never called. With `new Image()` you're just creating that object, not calling `Image#onCreate`. You need to [launch the Image activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) from your MainActivity. And no need to call `new Image()` actually.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare `Image` `Activity` in android manifest.